# Converting strings read from a file into a array or list

Tags: python

I have python code that generates sets of numbers as arrays and stores them in a file, the file looks like follows

```
  set([0, 2, 3])

  set([0, 1, 3])

  set([0, 1, 2])
```

I have another python code that reads this file and needs to convert the text line back to a array.

Method to read the file

```
def get_sets_from_file (self,file_name):
    file_handle = open(file_name, "r")
    all_sets_from_file = file_handle.read()
    print all_sets_from_file
```

Once the text line is read, I need a mechasism to convert the textline back to a array.

Thanks,

Bhavesh.

EDIT-1:

Based on the suggestions given below, i have changed the file format to use comma-seperated file

```
set([8, 6, 7]),
set([8, 5, 7]),
set([8, 4, 7]),
set([8, 3, 7]),
```

Comment: Are you saying that the file has that *exact* syntax?

Comment: I share @Makoto 's concern. You should use CSV formatted text, one line per set. They have an entire module dedicated to using this format, so you know its gotta be good!

Comment: @Makoto , yes the file format is currently not comma separated. I could try and make the file comma separated.

Comment: Do the sets only contain integers, or can there be floating point numbers as well?

Comment: @ekhumoro , for numbers the file only contains integers and doesnt contain any floating point numbers

Comment: `generates sets of numbers as arrays` this is not an array in python. This is a python list. An array would look like `array('i', [1, 2, 3, 4])` (array array) or `array([1, 2, 3, 4])` (numpy array)

Comment: About your edit...by csv, I meant: `8,6,7\n` `8,5,7\n` `8,4,7\n`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can apply this to each line in your file:

```
>>> line = "set([0, 2, 3])"    #or "set([0, 2, 3]),"

>>> import re
>>> r = "set\(\[(.*)\]\)"
>>> m = re.search(r, line)
>>> match = m.group(1)
>>> a = [int(item.strip()) for item in match.split(',')]
>>> a
[0, 2, 3]
>>>
```

that could be implemented in your code as:

```
def get_sets_from_file (self,file_name):
    total = []
    with open(file_name, "r") as fhdl:
        for line in fhdl:
            a = do_the_regex_thing_above
            total.append(a)
    return total
```

**edit** (based on the comments from @Droogans):
this code will work perfectly with no change for the csv version of your document as you depicted it in the new edit.
However, the problem would be greatly simplified if you have access to the code that produces the current output. If this is the case, it would be more effective to [pickling](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) or [jsoning](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) your data. In this way you could recover your sets of list simply by pickle- or json-loading the generated output

Comment: I feel this solution is bordering on overkill for parsing sets. You might as well hunt squirrels with an elephant gun.

Comment: what do you propose ? If the question stays as first stated this is not about **parsing sets** but about **parsing text that contains the text "set"**. That's a very different thing. You could use eval but this is not really a good idea.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you suggested not storing the `__repr__` results of the sets in a text file to begin with. The answer works, it answers the OPs question...by definition it's a perfect answer...but could there be a different way? I recommended a CSV approach, but I can only comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your file contains properly formed python code.  You can use this:
read each line of the file into a variable (m)

```
>>> m = "set([1, 3, 2])"
>>> eval(m)
set([1, 2, 3])
>>>
```

eval is considered very dangerous because it will do anything you ask it to (like reformat your disk or whatever).  But since you know what is in the file you want to evaluate this might be the way for you to go.

Comment: You should be very careful with this as the OP says: "I have python code...". So, if you are not **completely** sure what that code you have/got from somewhere is doing, don't use eval to parse the results of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read and write simple lists of integers to/from a file:

```
import os

sets = [
    set([0, 2, 3]),
    set([0, 1, 3]),
    set([0, 1, 2]),
    ]

def write_sets(path, sets):
    with open(path, 'wb') as stream:
        for item in sets:
            item = ' '.join(str(number) for number in item)
            stream.write(item + os.linesep)

def read_sets(path, sets):
    sets = []
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
        for line in stream:
            sets.append(set(int(number) for number in line.split()))
    return sets

path = 'tmp/sets.txt'

write_sets(path, sets)

print read_sets(path, sets)
# [set([0, 2, 3]), set([0, 1, 3]), set([0, 1, 2])]
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you serialize your data in something that you can easily deserialize from a string ?
[JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) perfectly fits here.

Comment: -1 sorry but this is a suggestion, not an answer to the post. It belongs in a comment.

Comment: Ok Liam Neelson, very cleaver. So you think it is a bad suggestion and it is better to mislead the one who asked the question ? This is design question here, don't need to over-elaborate if the idea is rejected.

Comment: I have nothing against JSON in particular...I would, however, expect to be downvoted if all my answers said `"Why don't you hire <a href="www.myconsultingwebsite.com">me</a> to fix it for you?`". Technically, it's an answer...but it's not addressing the issue.

Comment: I have given a clear direction, why are you trying to travesty my words with an absurd comparaison ? This is insulting. You'd better be overzealous in studying computer sciences ; *"I'm gonna serialize some Python `sets` as CSV-files, obviously ! Both hold values comma-separated"*. Seriously, that's just funny.

Comment: I think json is a good fit. I would have upvoted the comment.